# Generate CSV from JSON with JQ with nested levels

Tags: json, jq

I'm struggling somehow to create a nice jq-Query to generate a proper CSV like the below from following JSON example:

```
[
  {
    "regisseur": "Steven Spielberg",
    "movies": [
      "War of the Worlds",
      "Jurassic Park"
    ]
  },
  {
    "regisseur": "George Lucas",
    "movies": [
      "Howard The Duck",
      "Hook"
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'd like to get is a CSV-representation of it looking like this:

```
Steven Spielberg;War of the Worlds;
Steven Spielberg;Jurassic Park;
George Lucas;Howard The Duck;
George Lucas;Hook;
```

I especially want to achieve this with one single jq - call for performance-reasons and I'd like to avoid to iterate over it for each regisseur (at least within bash; jq may do iterate, as long as it is fast)

(The example here is just small, in reality I have to look at many more records, hence the emphasis on performance)

I could do it by getting a list of all regisseurs, externally iterate over it and then ask for the list of movies per that regisseur and make the CSV.

However this is not performant enough and I do not know how to script such within jq itself.

Comment: There's a nice [jq tutorial](https://exercism.org/tracks/jq/concepts) that might help.

Comment: That's nice! Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
jq -r '.[] | .regisseur as $r | .movies[] | [$r, .] | @csv'
```

Will output proper CSV

```
"Steven Spielberg","War of the Worlds"
"Steven Spielberg","Jurassic Park"
"George Lucas","Howard The Duck"
"George Lucas","Hook"
```

For semicolon separated, you could pipe that into another tool like [miller](/questions/tagged/miller) or [csvkit](/questions/tagged/csvkit), or you could hope the input data contains no semicolons and do

```bash
jq -r '.[] | .regisseur as $r | .movies[] | [$r, .] | join(";")'
```

Comment: Perfect, .... that's awesome. Well, the semicolon isn't that important in this case. My focus was mainly on the repeating regisseur for column 1.
I clearly get the technique now, thanks a lot !